# Will TypeScript errors break the CI build?

Tags: git, typescript, azure-devops

I have a scenario where our Visual Studio Online Git hosted solution is having the Continuous Integration (CI) build complete successfully, yet there are build errors locally.

These build errors local to the VS.NET solution are however isolated to TypeScript build errors. My understanding is that TypeScript build errors will certainly cause local build failures, but *will not* prevent the CI build server from completing successfully. This is because the `tsc.exe` TypeScript compiler will simply transpile the `.ts` files into `.js` files on the build server, but any associated errors will not be blocking at that point. The solution only cares about the output `.js` files and hence they exist after compiling and that satisfies the build server.

I'm however not 100% sure on this, and would like clarification if this is correct, or if there is something else that allows local TypeScript errors to *not* affect the build server outcome?

Comment: Could the build artifacts from previous (successful) builds still exist on the build server? Even though the current build fails, because the output `.js` files from the previous build is there, the rest of the build might succeed. If so, you would expect to see issues running the code due to expected code generation not to have happened.

Comment: Even if they did a .js file has no build server compile checking as it is just a scripting language. Unless it is altogether missing, it would still work even if the .js was bad. This is also a brand new build of an app port, so there would not be any successful builds prior to introducing the .ts issues. This means the .js files have been created. You are correct though, the running code for sure will have issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but will not prevent the CI build server from completing successfull

It will most likely cause the build to fail *unless* some one explicitly *ignores* the error code returned from the build process (which is a very bad idea to begin with).

Comment: This is puzzling. Digging into the logs the .sln build succeeds and it's kind of a vanilla VSO build setup from what I see. I don't see how my local errors don't break the build server. Question - these TypeScript errors are quite new and only I believe since I upgraded my TS tooling to 1.6. This TS worked previously and is all of the sudden causing build errors (I'm about to post another question with the issue I can't understand). Regardless, I wonder if the build server has an older version of the `tsc.exe` compiler that would allow these errors not to be blocking?

Comment: `I wonder if the build server has an older version of the tsc.exe compiler that would allow these errors not to be blocking` indeed

Comment: The issue was (2) fold from what I can tell: **1.** An older version of the compiler on the server didn't compain about the TypeScript errors because they were not violations in that older version. **2.** In `VS2015` there is an option in the `Errors` window that states `Build + Intellisense` which is on by default. The errors I was noting were _Intellisense_ errors. If I switched to `Build Only` the errors were non-blocking locally when building.